# How to store uploaded mulitple pdf file to a specific location in java?

Tags: java, file-upload, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

i want to store uploaded file in a specific location in java.  if i upload `a.pdf` then i want it to store this at `"/home/rahul/doc/upload/"`. i went through some questions and answers of stack overflow but i am not satisfied with solutions.

i am working with `Play Framework 2.1.2`. i am not working with `servlet`.

i am uploading but it is storing file into temp directory but i want that file store into a folder as not a temp file i want that file  like a.pdf in folder not like temp file.

```
public static Result upload() {
    MultipartFormData body = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
    FilePart filePart1 = body.getFile("filePart1");
    File newFile1 = new File("path in computer");
    File file1 = filePart1.getFile();
    InputStream isFile1 = new FileInputStream(file1);
    byte[] byteFile1 = IOUtils.toByteArray(isFile1);
    FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(newFile1, byteFile1);
    isFile1.close();

}
```

but i am not satisfied with this solution and i am uploading multiple doc files.

for eg. i upload one doc ab.docx then after upload it is storing temp directory and file is this:

[image: uploaded file as temp]

and it's location is this: `/tmp/multipartBody5886394566842144137asTemporaryFile`

but i want this:  `/upload/ab.docx`

tell me some solution to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

Everything's correct as a last step you need to `renameTo` the temporary file into your upload folder, you don't need to play around the streams it's as simple as:

```
public static Result upload() {
    Http.MultipartFormData body = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
    FilePart upload = body.getFile("picture");

    if (upload != null) {
        String targetPath = "/your/target/upload-dir/" + upload.getFilename();
        upload.getFile().renameTo(new File(targetPath));
        return ok("File saved in " + targetPath);
    } else {
        return badRequest("Something Wrong");
    }
}
```

BTW you should implement some checking if targetPath doesn't exist to prevent errors and/or overwrites. Typical approach is incrementing the file name if file with the same name already exists, for an example sending `a.pdf` three times should save the files as `a.pdf`, `a_01.pdf`, `a_02.pdf`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

i just completed it. My solution is working fine.

**My solution of uploading multiple files is :**

```
public static Result up() throws IOException{

            MultipartFormData body = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
                List<FilePart> resourceFiles=body.getFiles();
                InputStream input;
                OutputStream output;
                File part1;
                String prefix,suffix;
                for (FilePart picture:resourceFiles) {

                 part1 =picture.getFile();
                  input= new FileInputStream(part1);
                  prefix = FilenameUtils.getBaseName(picture.getFilename()); 
                    suffix = FilenameUtils.getExtension(picture.getFilename());

                    part1=new File("/home/rahul/Documents/upload",prefix+"."+suffix);
                    part1.createNewFile();

                    output = new FileOutputStream(part1);
                    IOUtils.copy(input, output);
                    Logger.info("Uploaded file successfully saved in " + part1.getAbsolutePath());

                }
```